# Use an integer to test a combination of enum values

Tags: c#

I have seen something like this in practice before, but I cannot find out what the name of this technique is called to be able to google it.

I want to achieve this:

```
public enum Directions
{
    Top = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Bottom = 4,
    Left = 8
}
```

And then generate a random combination of those directions:

```
int combinationOfDirections = Random.Range(1, 15);
```

.. so the minimum could be 1, and the max 15 (1 + 2 + 4 + 8).

What method could I use to test which combination of top, right, bottom and left were picked. Something like:

```
// 'includes' is just the English version of what I want to do
if(combinationOfDirections includes Directions.Bottom)
```

I'm sure it was something using a '|' or an '&'.. any help would be hot!

Thanks

Comment: You need to cast the random number to then enumable Directions.  bTry following :            Random rand = new Random();
            Directions[] randomDirections = Enumerable.Range(1, 15).Select(x => (Directions)Math.Pow(2,rand.Next(0,4))).ToArray();

Comment: @Dimitar very helpful thank you! That makes sense now

Comment: What you are doing in this case doesn't make sense.  What does a combination of Top and Bottom, or Left and Right set at the same time mean?  I think you have a cell with 8 surrounding cells and you want to choose one of 8 different values (not 15 different values).

Comment: Sorry I deleted it. I will elaborate more this comment. Essentially the values you set to the enumeration members should be powers of 2, so every member can represent a bit. For example first member represents the 2 to the zero power and so on. So by using the bitwise operators | an & you essentially set values and check if they are set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to check if a direction was included:

```
public static bool isDirectionAvailable(Directions direction, int value)
{
    return ((int)direction & value) != 0;
}
```

Comment: using bit-wise operator and "&" ands the bits of both values. Eg: 2 & 4 eqauls zero since 2 is 010b and 4 is 100b, anding the corresponding bits would result in 000b. Keeping this concept in mind, you can do this to extract included values. For the value 12 i.e.: 1100b, anding it with Top(1 = 0001b) or Right (2 = 0010b) would result in 0 = 0000b, while doing this with Bottom(4 = 0100b) would give 0100b which the same value of Bottom. Same goes for Left.  
I hope I made this clear enough

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable like that:

```
var dirs = (Directions)combinationsOfDirections;
```

You can check if a single directions is contained by using the [`HasFlag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
bool hasTop = dirs.HasFlag(Directions.Top);
```

To check if the values is *exactly* a specified combination, you can do:

```
bool isExactlyTopAndBottom = dirs == Directions.Top | Directions.Bottom;
```

Comment: This seems to be the most simple and inclusive answer, would you mind including what the & symbol does as shown in Sohaib's answer?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Op wants a random direction and how can you have both top and bottom set at same time?  Or left and right set at same time?

Comment: @jdweng no, they asked for a "random combination of those directions"... the rest is basic c# syntax.

Comment: The OP is confused?  You can't go both left and right at the same time.